# How can I see documentation generated from PHPDocumentor?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I suppose the title say it all.

I have all of my codes in ./src. Changed my PWD to `./src` and then run `phpdoc -d ./`. It runs rather okay, I suppose. There are a lot of warnings, but those are expected since I currently only have one documentation for a method.

There is ./output generated, but then I don't know which file to open to see my generated PHP documentation. I suppose, there is an index.html file, but there are none. **Which file I should open to see my generated PHP documentation?**

Answer (score 0):

PHPDocumenter provided from PEAR is outdated, please refer to their [GitHub](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2) on how to download the recent version of PHPDocumentor.

After downloading the recent version, my documentation runs fine, and index.html can be, then, found in the root of "output" folder.